# No application has connected to the REPL server

Tags: visual-studio-code, clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, shadow-cljs

I am trying to evaluate some Clojure forms in VS Code using the Calva REPL.

When I run any of [these](https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva/wiki/Commands-the-Top-10) commands, I get the error:

> No application has connected to the REPL server. Make sure your JS environment has loaded your compiled ClojureScript code.

It doesn't seem to let me switch namespaces.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a webpage up and connected?

Comment: Yep by running `lein dev` in the terminal. Are they connected somehow?

Comment: Did you open a browser window and visit the URL?

Comment: Thanks - yes I did

Answer (score 0):

By the comments to the question I am assuming this is a browser project. And by the error message, that it is shadow-cljs.

With shadow-cljs Calva opens up the REPL window a bit prematurely, because we still lack a reliable way to ensure the connection to the ClojureScript application. Once you have the prompt, like you have there (embarrassingly `undefined`), try reloading the web page with the application. You *should* be able to evaluate something then, and the prompt should get something less undefined.

I can recommend joining the [#calva channel on the Clojurians Slack](https://clojurians.slack.com/messages/calva/), for faster help.

Comment: I may be facing a similar issue but with a node project. Is there a way to fix this in my case or does it fall down to the same issue you're describing? Happy to make a separate post with detailed information if you prefer.

Comment: Calva itself is built partly as a shadow-cljs node project so there is hope!  But, yes, a separate question with some more details would help.Some node projects won't allow an app-connected REPL, because they don't have a main entry point, but let's see what your details are first. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Good that you got it sorted out. Basically it is what I am trying to say with my answer here. The app needs to run.